# Multiple Turtles, multiple random movements

Tags: python, random

I have an assignment where I have to make a game in python with turtles.
I am able to generate a grid like I want to, and I am able to generate multiple different turtles. my 
- I have no clue where to start in terms of figuring out how to have each of my three ***different*** turtles each move throughout the board randomly, while staying on the grid line.
- the "game" must stop after two of the turtles have hit the edge of the screen, I do not know how to do this, either.

here is what I have so far:

```
import turtle
import random

turtle.pensize(2)
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-160,-160)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.color("green")
turtle.speed(0)
for i in range(4):
    turtle.forward(320)
    turtle.left(90)

for y in range(-160,160,80):
    for x in range(-160,160,80):

        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(x,y)
        turtle.pendown()

        for k in range(4):
            turtle.forward(40)
            turtle.left(90)

        turtle.end_fill()       

for y in range(-120,160,80):
    for x in range(-120,160,80):

        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(x,y)
        turtle.pendown()
        for k in range(4):
            turtle.forward(40)
            turtle.left(90)


billy = turtle.Turtle()
billy.shape("turtle")
billy.color("red")
billy.penup()
billy.left(90)


rick = turtle.Turtle()
rick.shape("turtle")
rick.color("orange")
rick.penup()



mike = turtle.Turtle()
mike.shape("turtle")
mike.color("purple")
mike.penup()




turtle.done()
```

strong guidance would be VERY helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of object orientation.  Here is my version of your turtle script:

```
import turtle
import random
# I added randint. 
from random import randint

# Let's define a class so we can create turtles
class MyTurtle():

  # Here's the constructor. Where we give some initial values.
  def __init__(self, name, color):
    self.name = name
    self.color = color
    self.turtle = turtle.Turtle()
    self.turtle.shape("turtle")
    self.turtle.color(self.color)
    self.turtle.speed(1)
    self.turtle.pd()

  # We need to know if this turtle is off the board.
  def off_board(self):
    x = self.turtle.xcor()
    y = self.turtle.ycor()
    return x < -160 or 160 < x or y < -160 or 160 < y

  # calling this will move the turtle in a random direction.
  def move(self):
    turn = randint(0,2)
    if turn == 1:
      self.turtle.lt(45)
    elif turn == 2:
      self.turtle.rt(45)
    self.turtle.forward(5)

# Put your code for drawing the grid 

# Let's create some turtles and start moving them.
turtles = []
turtles.append( MyTurtle('billy', 'red'))
turtles.append( MyTurtle('chris', 'blue'))
turtles.append( MyTurtle('lilly', 'pink'))
turtles.append( MyTurtle('kevin', 'green'))

ok = True
while ok:
  for t in turtles:
    t.move()
    if t.off_board():
      print ("Turtle %s wins!!!" % (t.name))
      ok = False

turtle.done()
```

Come on! Just one upvote for this awesome turtle script?
[image]

Comment: maybe improvement `return -160 <= x <= 160 and -160 <= y <= 160` for off_board. doe youre turtles move `while staying on the grid line.`?

Comment: Well actually the OP says the program should run until two turtles move off the board.  I figured I should leave that as part of the assignment.  ;)